# Refactor jquery closure: How to refactor to nominal function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, closures

My code work (code testing) using a closure for add click event tu item of my calendar. If user click on day, code add on fly a row to table id myTable (datatable plugin)

```
$dowElement.addClass('event-clickable'); 
$('#' + id).click(function(){
     $('#myTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
            giCount+ ".1",
            giCount+ ".2",
            giCount+ ".3",
            giCount+ ".4"
        ]);
        giCount++;
 });
```

Try refactor for use a function, but not work.

```
 $dowElement.addClass('event-clickable'); 
 $('#' + id).click(jsonToTable());  // No work and broke calendar
```

Also try

```
$dowElement.addClass('event-clickable');
$('#' + id).click(function(){
    jsonToTable();
});
```

After first answer (edit) Not work if click but show days calendar with events.

```
$dowElement.addClass('event-clickable');
$('#' + id).click(jsonToTable);
```

It is clear that some part of working with javascript as I do not understand.

```
function jsonToTable() {

        $('#myTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
            giCount+ ".1",
            giCount+ ".2",
            giCount+ ".3",
            giCount+ ".4"
        ]);
        giCount++;
    }
```

Comment: Use `$('#' + id).click(jsonToTable);`. Use function reference, not invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `jsonToTable` reference. It isn't working because you invoke it and with that you pass its returning value.

```
$('#' + id).click(jsonToTable);
```

Comment: Also not work... edit my post for add this format. On this format, show calendar events, but when click not add data to table.

Comment: Does it find the `$('#' + id)` object? What does `$('#' + id).length` return?

Comment: Do you define `jsonToTable` BEFORE you pass it to the click function?

Comment: try with function jsonToTable before and after. Not work.

Comment: Is the function called? Put an `alert("hello");` or something in its first line to check it.

Comment: Yes. I try put a allert for testing, and show alert.

Comment: $('#' + id).click(jsonToTable);  Show alert when click, but not add code to datatable.

Comment: Then you have the answer to your question and your next problem is that the code doesn't act like you'd like to. That's another issue...

Comment: Forgiveness. I have not the wing answer questions. Perhaps I failed to ask the question. but the question is the code not working. 1. I have a code that serves as closure. 2 In the examples I put refactoring, and in any works. Refactor, you do the same. Do not do what I want. "Code refactoring is the process of restructuring existing computer code – changing the factoring – without changing its external behavior."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94800/discussion-between-abkrim-and-laszlokiss88).